# Outlier detection in non-normally distributed data

Tags: python, machine-learning, data-science, outliers

I have a big dataset, which contains yearly rapports of companies.
In this dataset I want to detect errors/outliers. These outliers are mainly human input errors.  I have trouble deciding which is the best strategy to use for this problem, since my data is not normal distributed.

My dataset contains about 100 columns.

Does anyone has some input on techniques, for detecting human errors?
Think of comma error, to many zeros, ect

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

Well looks it is a complicated problem.
Looks you data has following features.
1. NLP knowledge: company rapports piece of articles. To analysis it, NLP has to be adapted.
2. high dimention: currently you has about 100 columns, considering the NLP decomposed result, you might has thousands of columns in certain cases.
3. non normal distributed.

To solve it,  you may try to :
1. Use NLP way to transformat article to numeric information
2. Use typical novel or outlier tools to find it. you can try SKlearn model.
https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/outlier_detection.html

Hope it can help you.